# Concatenating tables with axis=1 in Orange python

Tags: python, orange

I'm fairly new to Orange.

I'm trying to separate rows of angle (elv) into intervals.
Let's say, if I want to separate my 90-degree angle into 8 intervals, or 90/8 = 11.25 degrees per interval.

Here's the table I'm working with

[image: Here's the table I'm working with]

Here's what I did originally, separating them by their elv value

[image: Here's what I did originally, separating them by their elv value]

Here's the result that I want, x rows 16 columns separated by their elv value.

[image: Here's the result that I want, x rows 16 columns separated by their elv value.]

But I want them done dynamically.
I list them out and turn each list into a table with x rows and 2 columns.

This is what I originally did

```py
from Orange.data.table import Table
from Orange.data import Domain, Domain, ContinuousVariable, DiscreteVariable
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

num = 10 #number of intervals that we want to seperate our elv into.
interval = 90.00/num  #separating them into degree/interval
low = 0
high = interval

table = []
first = []
second = []
for i in range(num):
    between = []
    if i != 0:  #not the first run
        low = high
        high = high + interval
    for row in in_data:    #Run through the whole table to see if the elv falls in between interval
        if row[0] >= low and row[0] < high:
            between.append(row)
    
    elv = "elv" + str(i)
    err = "err" + str(i)
    domain = Domain([ContinuousVariable.make(err)],[ContinuousVariable.make(elv)])
    data = Table.from_numpy(domain, numpy.array(between))

    print("table number ", i)
    print(data[:3])
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hYAf.png)

But as you can see, these are separated tables being assigned every loop.
And I have to find a way to concatenate axis = 1 for these tables.

Even the source code for Orange3 forbids this for some reason.

[image: Even the source code for Orange3 forbids this for some reason.]

Comment: Please add the code you use as text, and show what's the output you got with your code.

Comment: I edited the post as you said, thank you for reminding me.